# Does "git branch -a" list tags?

Tags: git

I'm using `git branch -a` to list all my remote branches.

```
remotes/origin/feature1
remotes/origin/feature2
remotes/client/feature1
remotes/client/feature2
```

I pick one and `checkout client/feature2` to it and that puts me in a `detached head` state which seems like I've checked out to a tag somewhere in history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does "git branch -a" list tags?

No, it lists branches.

---

```
$ git checkout client/feature2
```

> ... puts me in a detached head state which seems like I've checked out to a tag somewhere in history?

But a [remote branch](https://www.git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) *does* just point to a commit. You can't use it as a local branch, to check it out and work on it.

What you can do instead is create a local tracking branch and work on that - the remote branch is updated when you push.

```
$ git checkout -b feature2 client/feature2
```